# Why isn't my cucumber feature running

Tags: android-studio, testing, cucumber, settings

can someone please help me, I can't get the step definitions to work.  I've took a screen shot of the Andoid Studio work place, as i thought it be easier then explaining it all.  Basically I want to run the feature file myfeature.feature and when i do i want it to pick up the steps that are defined in the MyStepdef Class. I'm sure it an easy fix but this has not worked for me for a number of days

UPDATE!

I downloaded the skeleton class (as suggested) and even managed to run it in its own android workspace.  Tried to implement with my program, using the classes from the skeleton, same feature, same set up but cannot run it.

I tried to create the feature file from scratch, the using android to set the stepdefintions from that feature file and still cannot run it

My thoughts are that I have the gradle set up to run an other automated test, in which i had complication, now I got them perfect with the "solution" i posted [//stackoverflow.com/questions/36968728/android-studio-testing-library-dependencies-that-have-been-compiled-using-java/36975041#36975041]
I have a feeling that the automated test setup that works well with expresso will not run well for the cucumber feature tests.
Anytime I add the jvm (0.5) and delete the exclude statements the old error comes bacK

```
  This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1*
```

Anytime I apply the exclude cucumber-jvm-deps on to a dependecny, I can run the espresso tests but not the cucumber.feature - either it does not recognise steps or if run using the JUnit (as in the skeleton) setup I get a completely new error

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Didea.junit.sm_runner -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\hbill\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar;C:\Users\hbill\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-html\0.2.3\624a0c986088e32910336dd77aee5191c04a8201\cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test\runner\0.5\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test\runner\0.5\res;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test.espresso\espresso-idling-resource\2.2.2\res;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test.espresso\espresso-idling-resource\2.2.2\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-integration\1.3\5de0c73fef18917cd85d0ab70bb23818685e4dfd\hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.3.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.3.0\jars\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\23.3.0\res;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\2.0.1\516c03b21d50a644d538de0f0369c620989cd8f0\jsr305-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\hbill\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\23.3.0\support-annotations-23.3.0.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-vector-drawable\23.3.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-vector-drawable\23.3.0\res;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\23.3.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\23.3.0\res;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\gherkin\2.12.2\17138631fa20fd0e44a13e50d6b7be59cee1a94\gherkin-2.12.2.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.3.0\res;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.3.0\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test.espresso\espresso-core\2.2.2\res;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test.espresso\espresso-core\2.2.2\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test\exposed-instrumentation-api-publish\0.5\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test\exposed-instrumentation-api-publish\0.5\res;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test\rules\0.5\res;C:\Users\hbill\Documents\TheFoodHunt2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support.test\rules\0.5\jars\classes.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\479c1e06db31c432330183f5cae684163f186146\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-core\1.2.4\72790b1da44d8d3d2764c6aef29865ee228bbeb1\cucumber-core-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\17.0\9c6ef172e8de35fd8d4d8783e4821e57cdef7445\guava-17.0.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-junit\1.2.4\8a57b68486cff4da4f10019cb9c62c597a6d2861\cucumber-junit-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-android\1.2.4\cf6fd6b0de808c6b28bf8e9d22f6572a180930a3\cucumber-android-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup\javawriter\2.1.1\67ff45d9ae02e583d0f9b3432a5ebbe05c30c966\javawriter-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-java\1.2.4\57cca534b7abe43f6dd7624b90d3d97d33d3023d\cucumber-java-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\hbill\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\info.cukes\cucumber-jvm-deps\1.0.3\cccdeff234db8b12e91ae2529812f1240b4d5603\cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 boo.thefoodhunt.RunCukesTest
!!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.<init>(BaseTestRunner.java:5)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:54)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:48)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:205)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:188)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code -3
```

Now i hate to be defeated, but I think im just going to have to leave it and go around it somehow (even though its for testing coursework :/) because this has took so much out of my time, and eating in to my revision.

I have took the screen shots of my settings (in case of quick fix, silly mistake)

[JUnit - Run Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwLy7.png)

[Cucumber Feature Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMLzv.png)

TBH the suggestion below regarding the CLI, I'm not sure what is meant as this is the first time I tried to setup a testing enviroment, I understand it to be the set as a type of Main activity for the test to be ran? , but i do not know how to set it any other way.

The grade build dependcies :

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4') {
        exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
    }
    androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4') {
        exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
    }
    androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.2.4') {
        exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    compile 'info.cukes:gherkin:2.12.2'
    // androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.4') {
        exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-jvm:1.2.4'
    androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-html:0.2.3') {
        exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
    }
    compile 'info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.3'
```

Comment: the screen shot is in the link, ive not yet reached anough points to embed any images in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The message you see is that the steps are undefined but have implemented the stubs.

This tells me that the place you have implemented the stubs are not in the correct part of the classpath. There is probably something wrong with your glue.

You want the steps to be in the same package, or a sub-package, as the test runner. That is the class where you invoke the Cucumber runner.

I would consider adding a JUnit class annotated as in the https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton to run Cucumber.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

Note that this class has to be in the test classpath.

This is different from your current approach where you are using the CLI to invoke Cucumber.

Comment: Thomas! Hi again, thanks for your help (again).  I will have a go

Comment: No such luck Thomas but thanks for your time, I managed to get the skeleton running in its own studio workspace, but applying it to my project was still a no go.  I have updated, but unless I can get this sorted tonight or a quick fix tomorrow, i will have to give cucumber a miss :(